# chain together tensorflow operations as user defined function

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering whether there is an easy way to define a user defined tensorflow operation if it consists only of chained tensorflow operations. This is just to make code from being unnecessarily long, especially if the same operations must be performed on similar objects:

For example, if I want to define a feed forward mechanism on a neural network with 2 hidden layers, I will need to do this:

```
layer1_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.matmul(input,weights1) + biases1)
layer2_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.matmul(layer1_output,weights2) + biases2)
layer3_output = tf.nn.softmax(tf.nn.matmul(layer2_output,weights3) + biases2)
```

However, this oftentimes needs to be done for validation and test sets also, so I would like to define a function which would let me do all the operations in a single swoop so I could get something like this:

```
train_output = feed_forward(input_train)
test_output = feed_forward(input_test)...
```

This seems like something simple to do, but I can't seem to find the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this is just to define a Python function the builds your network:

```
def feed_forward(input_data):
    layer1_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.matmul(input_data, weights1) + biases1)
    layer2_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.matmul(layer1_output, weights2) + biases2)
    layer3_output = tf.nn.softmax(tf.nn.matmul(layer2_output, weights3) + biases2)
    return layer3_output
```

Depending on how you define your `weights` and `biases` variables, you might pass them in as arguments to the function, or use [`tf.get_variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#get_variable) to handle the construction and sharing of variables between different calls to the function.

Comment: Ok that works! I was browsing around a bit more and it appears that you can also just pass in the training and test sets into the training dataset placeholder used in the original definition with a new feed dictionary when evaluating accuracy. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#train-and-evaluate-the-model